# Duplication in results using php mysql and inner join

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have three drop list that contain retrieved values from the database from 3 different tables

governorate:

- governosrate_id
- governorate_name

district:

- district_id
- district_name

village:

- id
- village_name

memebrs:

- user_id
- user_name
- governorate
- district
- village
  what i want is when the user select **one of the three or all of them** drop list the system must display the result that are related to the selected one

but the problem is that when the user select from the governorate it work fine but when it select governorate and district it duplicate the result related to the selected value and if the user choose  governorate district and village the result become triples

anyone can help me ????

i will show the all the code of the three types

and if anyone have a complaint try to not beat me

## code:

## by governorate

```
//**********search by locationn***************************************//
if(isset($_POST['listbyq']))
{    
//********************by governorate**************************************//
   if($_POST['listbyq']=="by_gov")
   {
       $bygov = $_POST['governorate'];
       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, 
    s.specialization_name,
    g.governorate_name,
    d.district_name,
    v.village_name 
          FROM members u
                       INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                        ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id
                        INNER JOIN governorate g
                        ON u.governorate = g.governorate_id
                        INNER JOIN districts d
                        ON u.district = d.district_id
                        INNER JOIN village v
                        ON u.village = v.id
                        WHERE governorate = '$bygov'")or die(mysql_error("Error: querying the governorate"));

       $num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
       if($num_row > 0 )
       {
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
           {
              $row_id = $row['user_id'];
              $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
              $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
              $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
              $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];
              $row_spec = $row['specialization_name'];
              $row_gov = $row['governorate_name'];
              $row_dist = $row['district_name'];
              $row_village = $row['village_name'];

                ////***********for the upload image*************************//
         $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
         $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
         if(file_exists($check_pic))
         {
             $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
         }
         else
         {
             $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
         }

          $outputlist.='
     <table width="100%">
                 <tr>
                    <td width="23%" rowspan="5"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href =              "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                    <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                    <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                      <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                     <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                     <td><div align="right">Job:</div></td>
                     <td>'.$row_spec.'</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                     <td><div align="right">Location:</div></td>
                     <td>'.$row_gov.'__'.$row_dist.'__'.$row_village.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <hr />
            ';

           }
       }

   }
   else
   {
       $errorMSG = "No member within this selected governorate";
   }
```

## by district

```
 if($_POST['listbyqa']=="by_dist")
   {
      @ $bydist = $_POST['district'];
       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, 
    s.specialization_name,
    g.governorate_name,
    d.district_name,
    v.village_name 
          FROM members u
                       INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                        ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id
                        INNER JOIN governorate g
                        ON u.governorate = g.governorate_id
                        INNER JOIN districts d
                        ON u.district = d.district_id
                        INNER JOIN village v
                        ON u.village = v.id
                       WHERE district = '$bydist'")or die(mysql_error("Error: querying the district"));

       $num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
       if($num_row > 0 )
       {
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
           {
              $row_id = $row['user_id'];
              $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
              $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
              $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
              $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];
              $row_spec = $row['specialization_name'];
              $row_gov = $row['governorate_name'];
              $row_dist = $row['district_name'];
              $row_village = $row['village_name'];

                ////***********for the upload image*************************//
         $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
         $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
         if(file_exists($check_pic))
         {
             $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
         }
         else
         {
             $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
         }

          $outputlist.='
     <table width="100%">
                 <tr>
                    <td width="23%" rowspan="5"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href =              "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                    <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                    <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                      <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                     <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                     <td><div align="right">Job:</div></td>
                     <td>'.$row_spec.'</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                     <td><div align="right">Location:</div></td>
                     <td>'.$row_gov.'__'.$row_dist.'__'.$row_village.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <hr />
            ';

           }
       }

   }
   else
   {
       $errorMSG = "No member within this selected District";
   }
```

## by village

```
if($_POST['listbyqb']=="by_city")
   {
       echo $_POST['listbyqb'];
      @ $byvillage = $_POST['village'];
       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, 
    s.specialization_name,
    g.governorate_name,
    d.district_name,
    v.village_name 
          FROM members u
                       INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                        ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id
                        INNER JOIN governorate g
                        ON u.governorate = g.governorate_id
                        INNER JOIN districts d
                        ON u.district = d.district_id
                        INNER JOIN village v
                        ON u.village = v.id
                       WHERE village = '$byvillage'")or die(mysql_error("Error: querying the district"));

       $num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
       if($num_row > 0 )
       {
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
           {
              $row_id = $row['user_id'];
              $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
              $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
              $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
              $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];
              $row_spec = $row['specialization_name'];
              $row_gov = $row['governorate_name'];
              $row_dist = $row['district_name'];
              $row_village = $row['village_name'];

                ////***********for the upload image*************************//
         $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
         $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
         if(file_exists($check_pic))
         {
             $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
         }
         else
         {
             $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
         }

          $outputlist.='
     <table width="100%">
                 <tr>
                    <td width="23%" rowspan="5"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href =              "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                    <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                    <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                      <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                     <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                     <td><div align="right">Job:</div></td>
                     <td>'.$row_spec.'</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                     <td><div align="right">Location:</div></td>
                     <td>'.$row_gov.'__'.$row_dist.'__'.$row_village.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <hr />
            ';

           }
       }

   }
   else
   {
       $errorMSG = "No member within this selected District";
   }
}
```

Comment: SO is not a code review site. You are supposed to try to solve the problem, demonstrate what you have tried and ask a pointed question. In the FAQ, you will find hints on how to ask. No beating required.

Comment: Just use GROUP BY your any repeated filed in the end of every query.

Comment: What, pray tell, is the `specialization` table? Is it possible its contents are increasing the cardinality of your result set?

Comment: @ Ollie Jones i did not understand your question

Answer (score 0):

A few simple things worth trying:

1. echo or var_dump the $_POST result to ensure you are getting the data you think you are getting.  It may be this that is the cause of the problem.  You are probably getting more than one
2. It seems most likely that messy code is the cause of the problem here.  You have three output sections so you have three possible outputs, all of which can be triggered when the appropriate IF conditions are satisfied.  Try echoing 'Here' 'There' and 'Everywhere' or words of your choice from within each block - you will soon see where the suspect code is!
3. A better option might be to change your where clause to something like:

   ```
   WHERE village='[villagename from post]' OR district='[districtname from post'] OR governorate='[govname from post]'
   ```

This way you only need one IF and one ouput.  It also scales better.

1. Try running each sql with test data manually inserted (PHP myAdmin is very handy for this) and see if the problem is at sql or php level.
2. @ - try and avoid it.  Better to write code in a way that does not generate errors.  Did you put it there for an empty index erro?  If so, this might be your problem.  Check your HTML and see answer 1  above.